# Commit image in git tree using the GitHub api

Tags: json, image, github, github-api

When we use the GitHub REST API to create git trees, our json data that needs to be POSTed looks like this:

```
{"tree": [{"path": "final.txt", "mode": "100644", "type": "blob", "content": "some content"}, {"path": "another_one.txt", "mode": "100644", "type": "blob", "content": "some more content"}]}
```

Is it possible to commit an image to GitHub with this format?

Comment: Can you provide the link to the API you want to use?  There are several possible APIs here and the one I'm looking at doesn't have this format.

Comment: No problem. [https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/git#create-a-tree](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/git#create-a-tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you can encode the image in base64, then make a post request with that base64 string to create a `blob` using [https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/git/blobs](https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/git/blobs). Get the given `sha` of the blob and then create a json object as so:

`"tree": [{"path": "image.png", "mode": "100644", "type": "blob", "sha": "blob"}]`

Post this json object to the [GitHub tree API](https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/git/trees) and your image will be uploaded to your repository.